# Parallax Issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was creating a parallax effect in which the image and the text move in opposite direction to the movement of the mouse. That is happening inside an element called parallax-wrapper. But when I move out of the element I want the image and the text to return back to their original positions. I have tried to detect the mouse position outside the element but for some reason it not firing properly.

The codepen link is - https://codepen.io/rohitgd/pen/gRLNad?editors=1010

HTML

```
<div class="parallax-wrapper">
    <div class="layer" data-mouse-parallax="0.1">
    <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingBackgroundShapes/img/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
    <div class="layer" data-mouse-parallax="0.3">REVERT</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
        background-color:#fff;
        padding: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }


    .parallax-wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color:#0c0c0c;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;

        .layer {
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            position: absolute;
      left: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 300px;
            font-size: 38px;
            color:#FFF;
            transition: all 200ms ease-out;
        }

    }

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  right: 70px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(".parallax-wrapper").mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - $(this).width() / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() / 2;

  $("*[data-mouse-parallax]").each(function() {
    var factor = parseFloat($(this).data("mouse-parallax"));
    x = -x * factor;
    y = -y * factor;

    $(this).css({ transform: "translate3d( " + x + "px, " + y + "px, 0 )" });
  });
});

$(document).mouseleave(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);

    if( !target.is("div.layer")) {
      alert('out of the element');
      e.stopPropagation();


    }
});
```

What I want is when the mouse is outside the parallax-wrapper the Image and the text return back to their original positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a selector was wrong. [Here's a correct version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjbMqo?editors=1010) or see code below.

To show better when you are inside/outside I change the background color, that's better than an alert. When you leave the wrapper (the black background) it flips correctly now.

Where RED is set you can reset the transform to the origin.

```js
// Trying to replicate the effect here - https://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingBackgroundShapes/

$(".parallax-wrapper").mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - $(this).width() / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() / 2;

  $(".parallax-wrapper").css("background-color", "#00ff00"); // <-- EXIT
  // reset transform here
  
  $("*[data-mouse-parallax]").each(function() {
    var factor = parseFloat($(this).data("mouse-parallax"));
    x = -x * factor;
    y = -y * factor;

    $(this).css({ transform: "translate3d( " + x + "px, " + y + "px, 0 )" });
  });
});

// this is the selector I changed from "document" to ".parallax-wrapper"
$(".parallax-wrapper").mouseleave(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);

    if( !target.is("div.layer")) {
      $(".parallax-wrapper").css("background-color", "#ff0000"); // <-- ENTER
      e.stopPropagation();


    }
});
```

```css
 body {
  background-color:#fff;
  padding: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }


 .parallax-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:#0c0c0c;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  .layer {
   width: 80%;
   height: 80%;
   position: absolute;
      left: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 300px;
   font-size: 38px;
   color:#FFF;
   transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  }
  
 }

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  right: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax-wrapper">
 <div class="layer" data-mouse-parallax="0.1">
    <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingBackgroundShapes/img/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
 <div class="layer" data-mouse-parallax="0.3">REVERT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for. Instead of changing the background colour I did what @Archer wrote. Now it works perfectly fine!

Comment: glad to help. but there's another bug in your code, i think it's because of the CSS. when you leave the wrapper to the top it doesn't fire the event. most probably there's a positioning issue and you should use a different way to position the wrapper through CSS. but that's the matter of another question, without the parallax etc. **WAIT** or maybe not. I noticed this only happens on codepen. here on SO it's working fine

Comment: it's definitely a codepen issue, test if it's on your website, too!

Comment: Yes, it's an issue only on codepen. Works fine everywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You're not resetting the transformations when your mouse leaves.  You need to add this where you have the alert...

```
$(".parallax-wrapper").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $("*[data-mouse-parallax]").each(function() {
    $(this).css({ transform: "translate3d( 0, 0, 0 )" });
  });
});
```

Note that the `mouseleave` event is triggered when the mouse leaves `.parallax-wrapper`, not `document` as you previously had it.

Here's a modified codepen...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyBgYJ

Comment: I think its better to use `.mouseout()` in this case

Comment: @Chiller That would fire the event handler when the mouse leaves the child elements as well.  In this case `mouseleave` is easier and cleaner (it means you don't have to handle and ignore those extra events).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I combined your answer with the answer by @pid. Now it's working exactly as desired!

Comment: No worries - glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(document).mouseleave` with `$(".parallax-wrapper").mouseleave`.

```js
$(".parallax-wrapper").mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - $(this).width() / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - $(this).height() / 2;

  $("*[data-mouse-parallax]").each(function() {
    var factor = parseFloat($(this).data("mouse-parallax"));
    x = -x * factor;
    y = -y * factor;

    $(this).css({ transform: "translate3d( " + x + "px, " + y + "px, 0 )" });
  });
});

$(".parallax-wrapper").mouseleave(function(e) {
      alert('out of the element');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parallax-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parallax-wrapper .layer {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  right: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax-wrapper">
 <div class="layer" data-mouse-parallax="0.1">
    <img src="https://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingBackgroundShapes/img/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
 <div class="layer" data-mouse-parallax="0.3">REVERT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!